# Is it possible to set ClientHello random number from outside

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm new to OpenSSL and trying to extend the API. I would like to create `ClientHello` as custom as possible so to see how my server reacts to it.

My question is: How can I set the `Random` section in `ClientHello` from outside the library (within my program)?

[image: overriding openssl lib settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no interface for this. It is just using `RAND_pseudo_bytes` to generate the random bytes. But you might try to modify the source code to add your own hooks, probably `ssl23_client_hello` in `ssl/s23_clnt.c`.

EDIT: with the large code overhaul done with OpenSSL 1.1.0 the relevant code can be found in `ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c` function `tls_construct_client_hello` and it is using `ssl_fill_hello_random` (`ssl/s3_lib.c`) to generate the bytes which then calls `RAND_bytes`.

Comment: Thanks , I'll dig in ! .Are you familiar with latest major version (1.1.0) ? this file got changed there ... :(